# Opening message/rfc82 in PHP ticket system

Tags: php, email, attachment, rfc822

Recently I developed a goodworking ticket-system in PHP. Works like charm, even with attachments.

Now yesterday some tickets arrived with e-mails attached to it, as message/rfc822 files. Now the point is: can this files be read by PHP? Can they be read by the imap functions in PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: php can read any file. files are just sequences of bytes, and reading bytes is easy. yes, php can talk to imap servers, but that's irrelevant if your mail server is (say) pop3-only.

Comment: Well, that is not the case. The point is, the message/rfc822 file is saved as - indeed - just a file. But how can I force PHP to read it just like another e-mail? Like outlook does?